# Database info not showing from my loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I new to php and learning and need some advice on shoing my database info within a loop which includes html, My page is blank so am wondering why my php isnt valid:

```
<?php include 'incudes/connect_db.php'; ?>

    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="topbarblock1">Dashboard</div>
        <div class="topbarblock2">Username</div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <div class="middle">
        <div class="middleblock1">Dashboard</div>
        <div class="middleblock2">
            <div class="container">
            <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>  
                <h2>
                    User Management
                    <hr />
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="containermain">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="th1">User Id</th>
                        <th class="th2">Username</th>
                        <th class="th3">Email Address</th>
                        <th class="th4">Details</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td1">#</td>
                        <td class="td2"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                        <td class="td3"><?php $row['email']; ?></td>
                        <th class="td4">Edit</th>
                    </tr>                   
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php   
}
?>
```

I'm not looking for a straight out answer I am looking for some advice on how this should be laid out and learn best practices.

Comment: Maybe your database connection isn't working? You need to troubleshoot the basics like this. [Take a look at the procedural example here so you can diagnose error messages that MySQL may be spitting back at you](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php). Also, why are you outputting an entire table in your loop? It seems like you should be putting it around the `<tr>...</tr>` of the `$row` output.

Comment: @sjagr my table is connecting fine it will output the data without the html. So I need to wrap the <tr>

Answer (score 0):

Change the line that says

```
<td class="td3"><?php $row['email']; ?></td>
```

to

```
<td class="td3"><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
```

PHP will try to interpret the variable as some sort of command/statement otherwise and subsequently fail.

Also rethink where you wrap the loop as I previously mentioned, or else your HTML is going to end up wonky (you'll see this after you've fixed the code.)

You should also program by using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of your code so you can fix simple mistakes on your own

Comment: @user3725879 Sometimes PHP will still give you the White Screen of Death without outputting anything.. but it's still not working with the fix I also mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I think i is to do with the path to the connect_db.php file because I jus created another file on the root and it works, I have tried all options to get to it but it is failing still